Navigation bug when routing users with @AppStorage
I've encountered an interesting behavior (or maybe that is the intended behavior and I'm wrong). When I use @AppStorage to route users to onboarding or not, the first onboarding view is shown twice. Hard to explain, here is a gif:

After I click "Finish the onboarding" I must be navigated to MainView, but instead, First View somehow is shown again in between.
Still hard to explain, so here is the bare-bones SwiftUI code, which you can try yourself:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct OnboardingApp: App {
    @AppStorage("onboardingCompleted") var onboardingCompleted = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if !onboardingCompleted {
                FirstView()
            } else {
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome")
                
                NavigationLink("Second") {
                    SecondView()
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("First View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @AppStorage("onboardingCompleted") var onboardingCompleted = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Onboarding complete")
            Button("Finish the onboarding") {
                onboardingCompleted = true
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("Second View")
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @AppStorage("onboardingCompleted") var onboardingCompleted = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, Main View!")
                Button("Uncomplete onboarding") {
                    onboardingCompleted = false
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("Main View")
            }
        }
    }
}

Why is the FirstView shown again after the @AppStorage var changes?

In your gif, FirstView is not "shown again". It's just that its onAppear got called again. Why is that problematic?

Your wording is correct, what bothers me is the unexpected call of .onAppear(). I have my code in there, specifically analytics code to track the screen view. And so this screen is tracked twice.

FYI you shouldn't have different defaults for onboardingCompleted and you probably shouldn't even have multiple @AppStorage source of truths using the same key.

When the onboarding is completed, onboardingCompleted would be true, so you can use that to differentiate between "normal" onAppear calls, and the unexpected call that occurs when you move to MainView.
@AppStorage("onboardingCompleted") var onboardingCompleted = false

...

.onAppear {
    if !onboardingCompleted {
        print("First View")
    }
}

Alternatively, move onAppear to the NavigationStack instead.
Interestingly, this behaviour does not occur on macOS.
My guess (so take this with a grain of salt) is that SwiftUI implements the NavigationStack using a UINavigationController, and wraps each view on the stack into its own UIHostingController, and onAppear gets called in viewWillAppear. When moving to MainView, the UINavigationController gets popped to root for some reason, so FirstView's onAppear gets called.

I've also noticed that if we have more views in the onboarding, like First-Second-Third-Fourth, then Main. Still, only the First view's .onAppear() is called twice.
Anyway, your solution works, I've moved .onAppear() to the NavigationStack. Thank you very much.

Did you notice they have different default values for @AppStorage("onboardingCompleted")?

@malhal @AppStorage("onboardingCompleted") only becomes true on MainView after the onboarding is completed. I believe it should stay this way. Or do you see an error in it?

the var onboardingCompleted = true means use true as the default when there is no setting yet, it doesn't actually save it as true. It's best you keep the same default false as all of the other declarations and set it true in onAppear. However it might be a bad idea to have multiple @AppStorage with same key, maybe better to pass let or binding around to a single one.

@malhal the expected default value of onboardingCompleted is false during the onboarding, but true in the Main app. You are correct that @AppStorage doesn't set the value, the Button's do. I wish to know why having multiple @AppStorage with the same key is bad? I thought it was the intended use case.

I think if it was intended to have multiple then its projected value wouldn’t be a binding and there would be a way to declare the default value in one place.
